# Symfony + Api-platform: No encoder has been configured for account "App\Document\Users\User"

Tags: symfony, api-platform.com

I've got this error in symfony 5.1, api-platform 2.5 and MongoDB

```
No encoder has been configured for account "App\Document\Users\User".
```

The error occurs, when i'm trying to add user via Swagger and i think its typo mistake or i didn't configure something. I was searching several similar questions, but those didn't help me.

Also there is in use UserDataPersister class copied from here: https://symfonycasts.com/screencast/api-platform-security/encode-user-password

Below my code:

```
#config/packages/security.yaml
security:
    encoders:
        App\Document\Users\User:
            algorithm: auto

    role_hierarchy:
        ROLE_USER: ROLE_USER
        ROLE_ADMIN: ROLE_ADMIN
        ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN: ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN

    providers:
        app_user_provider:
            class: App\Document\Users\User

    firewalls:
        dev:
            pattern: (^/_(profiler|wdt))|(^/test)
            security: false
        main:
            pattern:  ^/
            stateless: true
            anonymous: true
            provider: app_user_provider

    access_control:
        - { path: ^/api, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY }
```

```
<?php
//  src/Document/Users/User.php

namespace App\Document\Users;

use Doctrine\ODM\MongoDB\Mapping\Annotations as ODM;
use ApiPlatform\Core\Annotation\ApiResource;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\UserInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Serializer\Annotation\SerializedName;
use Symfony\Component\Serializer\Annotation\Groups;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;
use DateTime;

/**
 * @ApiResource(
 *  normalizationContext={"groups"={"user:read"}},
 *  denormalizationContext={"groups"={"user:write"}},
 * )
 * @ODM\Document
 * @ODM\HasLifecycleCallbacks
 */
class User implements UserInterface
{
    /**
     * @ODM\Id(strategy="auto")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ODM\Field(type="string")
     * @Groups({"user:read", "user:write"})
     */
    private $email;

    /**
     * @ODM\Field(type="collection")
     * @Groups({"user:read", "user:write"})
     */
    private $roles = [];

    /**
     * @ODM\Field(type="string")
     * #Groups({"user:write"})
     * @Assert\DisableAutoMapping()
     */
    private $password;

    /**
     * @ODM\Field(type="string")
     * @SerializedName("password")
     * @Groups({"user:write"})
     * @Assert\Length(max=4096)
     */
    private $plainPassword;

    /**
     * @ODM\Field(type="string")
     * @Groups({"user:read", "user:write"})
     */
    private $username;

    /**
     * @ODM\Field(type="string")
     * @Groups({"user:read", "user:write"})
     */
    private $firstname;

    /**
     * @ODM\Field(type="string")
     * @Groups({"user:read", "user:write"})
     */
    private $lastname;

    /**
     * @ODM\Field(type="string")
     */
    private $pseudo;

    /**
     * @ODM\Field(type="string")
     * @Groups({"user:read", "user:write"})
     */
    private $contact;

    /**
     * @ODM\Field(type="boolean")
     * @Groups({"user:read", "user:write"})
     */
    private $enabled;

    /**
     * @ODM\Field(type="date")
     * @Groups({"user:read"})
     */
    private $created_at;

    /**
     * @ODM\Field(type="date")
     * @Groups({"user:read"})
     */
    private $updated_at;

    /**
     * @ODM\Field(type="date")
     * @Groups({"user:read"})
     */
    private $last_login;

    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    public function getEmail(): ?string
    {
        return $this->email;
    }

    public function setEmail(string $email): self
    {
        $this->email = $email;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * A visual identifier that represents this user.
     *
     * @see UserInterface
     */
    public function getUsername(): string
    {
        return (string) $this->username;
    }

    /**
     * @see UserInterface
     */
    public function getRoles(): array
    {
        $roles = $this->roles;
        $roles[] = 'ROLE_USER';

        return array_unique($roles);
    }

    public function setRoles(array $roles): self
    {
        $this->roles = $roles;
        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @see UserInterface
     */
    public function getPassword(): string
    {
        return (string) $this->password;
    }

    public function setPassword(string $password): self
    {
        $this->password = $password;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getPlainPassword(): ?string
    {
        return $this->plainPassword;
    }

    public function setPlainPassword(string $plainPassword): self
    {
        $this->plainPassword = $plainPassword;
        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @see UserInterface
     */
    public function getSalt()
    {
        // not needed when using the "bcrypt" algorithm in security.yaml
        return null;
    }

    /**
     * @see UserInterface
     */
    public function eraseCredentials()
    {
        // If you store any temporary, sensitive data on the user, clear it here
        $this->plainPassword = null;
    }

    public function setUsername(string $username): self
    {
        $this->username = $username;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getFirstname(): ?string
    {
        return $this->firstname;
    }

    public function setFirstname(?string $firstname): self
    {
        $this->firstname = $firstname;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getLastname(): ?string
    {
        return $this->lastname;
    }

    public function setLastname(?string $lastname): self
    {
        $this->lastname = $lastname;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getPseudo(): ?string
    {
        return $this->pseudo;
    }

    public function setPseudo(?string $pseudo): self
    {
        $this->pseudo = $pseudo;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getContact(): ?string
    {
        return $this->contact;
    }

    public function setContact(?string $contact): self
    {
        $this->contact = $contact;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getEnabled(): ?bool
    {
        return $this->enabled;
    }

    public function setEnabled(bool $enabled): self
    {
        $this->enabled = $enabled;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getCreatedAt(): ?\DateTimeInterface
    {
        return $this->created_at;
    }

    public function setCreatedAt(\DateTimeInterface $created_at): self
    {
        $this->created_at = $created_at;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getUpdatedAt(): ?\DateTimeInterface
    {
        return $this->updated_at;
    }

    public function setUpdatedAt(\DateTimeInterface $updated_at): self
    {
        $this->updated_at = $updated_at;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getLastLogin(): ?\DateTimeInterface
    {
        return $this->last_login;
    }

    public function setLastLogin(?\DateTimeInterface $last_login): self
    {
        $this->last_login = $last_login;

        return $this;
    }

    /** 
     * @ODM\PrePersist 
     * @ODM\PreUpdate
     */
    public function updatedTimestamps()
    {
        $dateTimeNow = new DateTime('now');
        $this->setUpdatedAt($dateTimeNow);
        if ($this->getCreatedAt() === null) {
            $this->setCreatedAt($dateTimeNow);
        }
    }

}
```

```
<?php
//  src/DataPersister/UserDataPersister.php

namespace App\DataPersister;

use ApiPlatform\Core\DataPersister\DataPersisterInterface;
use App\Document\Users\User;
use Doctrine\ODM\MongoDB\DocumentManager;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Encoder\UserPasswordEncoderInterface;

class UserDataPersister implements DataPersisterInterface
{
    private $entityManager;
    private $userPasswordEncoder;

    public function __construct(DocumentManager $entityManager, UserPasswordEncoderInterface $userPasswordEncoder)
    {
        $this->entityManager = $entityManager;
        $this->userPasswordEncoder = $userPasswordEncoder;
    }

    public function supports($data): bool
    {
        return $data instanceof User;
    }

    /**
     * @param User $data
     */
    public function persist($data)
    {
        if ($data->getPlainPassword()) {
            $data->setPassword(
                $this->userPasswordEncoder->encodePassword($data, $data->getPlainPassword())
            );
            $data->eraseCredentials();
        }

        $this->entityManager->persist($data);
        $this->entityManager->flush();
    }

    public function remove($data)
    {
        $this->entityManager->remove($data);
        $this->entityManager->flush();
    }
}
```

Comment: Start by doing the ever popular clearing of the cache.  Then run "php bin/console security:encode-password".  If no encoders are defined then you get an error.  If it prompts for a password then a least you know some encoder is defined.

Comment: I actually don't think your security.yaml file is even being loaded.  The reason is that you are missing the entity level under your providers.  Leaving it out triggers an error on my system.  Or it is possible you are running in production and the cache is not getting cleared.  https://symfony.com/doc/current/security/user_provider.html#entity-user-provider

Comment: after "php bin/console security:encode-password" CLI says: Encoder used       Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Encoder\MigratingPasswordEncoder; [OK] Password encoding succeeded

Comment: Is the security.yaml file in your question the actual file or did you edit it after pasting?  The reason I ask is I don't understand why you are not getting Unrecognized option "class" under "security.providers.app_user_provider".  Might want to double check and verify that the security.yaml file you are looking at is the actual file being used.

Comment: thank You @Cerad i've moved 'App\Document\Users\User' to 'App\Document\User' and now is almost ok ;) but password in mongoDB is not encoded; additionally in security.yaml was required to change to `providers: app_user_provider: mongodb: {class: App\Document\User, property: username}`

Comment: @Cerad unfortunately its very likely that somehow i've pasted here old security.yaml, almost the same looking

Comment: At least the mystery was solved.  Might want to double check that your UserDataPersister is being called.  A simple dump and die should do the trick.

Comment: problem with password encoding resolved ;) i forgot to change 'use App\Document\Users\User;' to 'use App\Document\User;' **my question can be considered closed** thank You @Cerad once again